# History of choice of 'Z' to represent high impedance?

Tags: history, tri-state, high-impedance

I'm curious to know why 'Z' was chosen to represent high impedance state for types such as used in VHDL and VHDL-AMS's std_logic_1164 logic system:

[image]

(image of page 789 of [The System Designer's Guide to VHDL-AMS: Analog, Mixed-Signal, and Mixed-Technology Modeling (Systems on Silicon) ISBN: 1-55860-749-8](http://a.co/098Ij3O))

"high-Z", "hi-Z" etc. seem to be in common use, but my Google Fu is not up to the task to identify the history. The [three state logic wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-state_logic) does not clarify it, nor does the [Use of 'Z' section of the IEEE_1164 wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1164#Use_of_'Z') indicate the history.

Comment: Z generally means impedance itself, and likely comes from the fact that it has a complex representation.  Complex numbers often are designated as z or Z, I seem to remember, from the German "Number", Zahl

Comment: I guess it's just because of lack of letters.

Comment: Why is X used for reactance and why c for speed of light?

Comment: @EugeneSh. that was my thought too. Perhaps it was that simple.  Nobody seems to know where it came from so far though, at least not yet.

Answer (score 6):

'Z' is the electrical symbol for impedance.

(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance)

Digital electronics has been using the terms like 'high Z' and 'hi-Z' for decades to mean 'in high-impedance state' or 'in tri-state'. It pre-dates VHDL.

So it's a logical step for 'Z' to be used as the single character notation for std_logic etc. for a signal in its high impedance state.

Comment: Sigh. Now I regret specifying VHDL and should have asked: "Who first used Z and why?" instead. But, +1 for your answer.

Comment: @bgoodr, errm you wrote a completely VHDL-centric question, talking about VHDL with a giant picture of a VHDL manual and get a VHDL answer...and "Sigh"? Wouldn't "Oops" be the word :-)

Comment: Yes. Change that to an Oops.